# Blog page with theme completely different from the main theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to make my [website](http://www.visualdeceptions.info) on Wordpress. I am using [Brave Zeenat](http://www.methemes.com/free-wordpress-themes/brave-zeenat/) as my primary and [Grido](http://themify.me/themes/grido) as my blog theme.

I have read many tutorials in places, which discuss how to apply a customized flavour of the main theme on a static page, e.g. Blog. However, the main theme I am using does not appeal to me as a blog theme at all, so I wanted to do something entirely different, so I have tried two methods.

First, I tried to just create a page named Blog and force it to take a theme of my choice using the [Page Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-theme/) plugin. That worked instantly, but the blog page is empty and would not accept articles of certain categories by default like this.

Second, I tried to not use any plugin at all, and use a custom PHP file instead, which sets some loops and calls a theme. This file `blog.php` had to be in the main theme directory, otherwise it would not be applicable as a template from the page settings in Wordpress dash.

So I put it with my main theme, but call to load the other theme, like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

$paged = get_query_var('paged');
query_posts('cat=0&paged='.$paged);

global $more;
$more = 0;

load_template(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/grido_v1.0.1/index.php');

?>
```

Eventually I only want to see category no.9, but for now, I left it as 0, which should display all categories. But when I run this with Page Theme plugin disabled, I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function themify_get() in /var/sites/v/visualdeceptions.info/public_html/wp-content/themes/grido_v1.0.1/index.php on line 10`.

Now, although this is a themify error, I am sure if I try to use other premium themes as well, I will encounter very similar errors, because I have only set a custom php file, and no style, header, footer, etc. But I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add getheader() and getfooter() in the code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
get_header(); //HERE

$paged = get_query_var('paged');
query_posts('cat=0&paged='.$paged);

global $more;
$more = 0;

load_template(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/grido_v1.0.1/index.php');

get_footer(); //HERE

?>
```

Comment: That did not solve it, because calling just `get_header()` and `get_footer()` from the main theme's directory would load the main theme's header and footer, whereas I want the header and footer of the blog theme. The `themify_get()` it complains about looks somewhat like [this](http://tinypaste.com/1a2cc1f7). I used `get_header(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/grido_v1.0.1/');` and `get_footer(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/grido_v1.0.1/');`, which also did not work. I am not importing something, I think. But I do not understand how to load the definition of that function `themify_get()`.

Comment: I think the main reason behind the error is that it cannot find functions.php, where that themify_get() is. But I don't know how to load functions.php separately, so I tried `define('TEMPLATEPATH', "../grido_v1.0.1/");` and `define('STYLESHEETPATH', "../grido_v1.0.1/");` but no change.

Comment: I told you to use get_header() and get_footer because I though that some functions needs to be loaded. And usually functions are imported within header or footer. So by what you said you are using your own header and footer?

Comment: Not really. The header and footer of the blog must also come from the blog theme, not the main theme. Grido also has header.php and footer.php and style.css, etc. So if I just call the header without defining the location of the other directory first, it will load the main header, not the blog theme header. Is that incorrect?